# Is it possible to make text touchable in Libgdx

Tags: button, fonts, libgdx, scene2d

I am creating a menu screen for my game and instead of creating button there I just have text font. I want to know whether it is possible to to make them touchable.as i have 3 text in main menu so  three different function.

Comment: Yes, but why not use TextButton and avoid the extra work?

Answer (score 0):

I have very little experience making GUIs in LibGDX, and I'm sure this answer is too late anyway, but:

**Why not just have a clickable object surrounding the text, and just don't render this?**

In other words, do what you'd do normally for a button, just don't render it.